# how to use attributes values in powershell script

Tags: powershell, chef-infra, chef-recipe, powershell-4.0

I am using `powershell_script` resource in chef to create a database in sqlserver 2012 here.

I have used database name as `test1` hardcoded in script. Now I want to provide the database name from the attribute file.

How can I get the value referenced from attribute file to the script.

```
powershell_script "create database" do
  code <<-EOH
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null

    $serverName = "localhost"

    $server = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $serverName

    #Create a new database
    $db = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database -argumentlist $server, "test1"
    $db.Create()

    #Reference the database and display the date when it was created. 
    $db = $server.Databases["Test_SMO_Database"]
    $db.CreateDate
  EOH
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now modified script look like this

```
powershell_script "create database" do
  code <<-EOH
  [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
  $serverName = "localhost"
  $server = new-object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $serverName
  #Create a new database
  $db = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database -argumentlist $server, "#{node['sqlserver']['dbname']}"
  $db.Create()
  EOH
end
```

**Attributes/default.rb**

```
default['sqlserver']['dbname'] = 'testing database'
```

now i can create database by using value in attribute file.

Thanks for you help  **IsabelHM**

Answer (score 1):

Spent a little bit of time figuring out the syntax to define an ***array*** as a node attribute and then pass it successfully to powershell_script. Apparently defining it as string is what works.

Attribute:

```
default['cookbook-name']['attribute-name'] = "'value1', 'value2', 'value3'"
```

And recipe:

```
powershell_script 'my script' do
  code <<-EOH
  $array = #{node['cookbook-name']['attribute-name']}
  ...
  EOH
  action :run
  guard_interpreter :powershell_script
  not_if "..."
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using attribute **environment** to pass variable (in this example: `dbname`) and then call it in the script as `$dbname`

There are two ways to setup the attributes.

***Method 1***

In attributes/default.rb, add this line

```
default['yourCookbookNameHere']['dbname'] = 'test1'
```

In recipes/default.rb

```
powershell_script "create database" do
  environment ({'dbname' => "#{node['yourCookbookNameHere']['dbname']}"})
  code <<-EOH
    $db = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database -argumentlist $server, $dbname
  EOH
end
```

***Method 2***

In your recipe, set it as local variable like this

```
localDbName = 'test1'

powershell_script "create database" do
  environment ({'dbname' => localDbName})
  code <<-EOH
    $db = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Database -argumentlist $server, $dbname
  EOH
end
```

Comment: modified the script as mentioned it is able to get the value passed in attribute file but still its failing with following error.                                 Compiled Resource:
     ------------------
        # Declared in c:/chef/cache/cookbooks/sqlserver/recipes/default.rb:1:in `from_file'
    
        powershell_script("create database") do
          action "run"
          retries 0
          retry_delay 2
          default_guard_interpreter :powershell_script
          command "create database"
          backup 5
          environment {"dbname"=>"testing database"}
          returns 0

Comment: What was the error? Could you post the attribute in your default.rb as well?

Comment: default.rb has the following value , correct me if its wrong                                                                                                                                                                                                                       if node['platform_family'] == 'windows' 
default['cookbook']['dbname']  = 'testing database'
end

Comment: @bbsys Do you want to get the param from the attribute default.rb file or a local variable in the recipe default.rb?

Comment: i want it from the attribute default,rb

Comment: modified my answer. You can choose either way to do it.

Comment: trying the first method but still getting the error msg http://pastebin.com/FgNfirqb   default.rb is also given along with the output.                                                                                                                                                                                                                       **NoMethodError
-------------
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass**

Comment: The indentation of your code seems to be the problem. Here is an example from the chef.io documentation as well. It's identical to what I gave you. Look at under the section "Pass an environment variable to a script": https://docs.chef.io/resource_powershell_script.html

Answer (score 0):

The current answers here using the `environment` property of `powershell_script` are incorrect in how they reference variables within the code block. Variables specified in the `environment` property are available as Environment Variables, not script variables, and have to be referenced as an environment variable like below:

```
powershell_script 'Passed-In Variable Example' do
  environment({ myVar: 'myvalue' })
  code <<-EOH
    Write-Output $env:myVar
  EOH
end
```

Basically, any of the other answers using the `environment` property to pass values in to the code block are *almost* correct, just make sure you prepend the variable name with `$env:` within the Powershell code.